# Getting a list of all the Kusto tables and related metadata with one row per table in result

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

With the following Kusto command we do get one row per table and then we also get complete schema information for that table:-

```
.show table MyTable cslschema
```

My requirement is just that -- in a single row , getting table all the information for a given table as a single row. The problem , though , is that I have to hardcode a specific table here. I would like to get this information for all the tables in a database with single command. Something like:-

```
.show table * cslschema
```

But obviously this doesn't work. Is there any workaround to achieve this? The end goal is to have one row per table -- and this should include all the info for a table, Folder, DocString as well as Schema, exactly what the above command returns but it should work for multiple tables.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use

```
.show database [DB] cslschema
```